# Fastest way to get a unique record from query set

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm new to django & I'm looking for best way to do following

I have a list of `user_ids` to update & 1 `user_id` by which all of them where updated. What I'm looking for is a way to use one single DB query to get both. Here is what I'm doing right now

```
    #users_ids > list of user_ids for updated users
    #updated_by > int

    users_ids.append(created_by)
    queryset = User.objects.filter(id__in=users_ids)
    created_by = queryset.get(id=updated_by)
    person_list = queryset.exclude(id=updated_by)
```

I'm wondering if django provides me a way to do get `created_by` & `person_list` in a single query, in a faster way to optimize performance. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just turn the first queryset into a list and use plain manual Python to pop out `created_by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
 queryset = User.objects.filter(id__in=users_ids).exclude(id=updated_by).filter(
                                id=updated_by).first()
```